# Does React have keep-alive like Vue js?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, infinite-scroll, react-router-v4

I made a Todo list with React js. This web has List and Detail pages.
There is a list and 1 list has 10 items. When user scroll bottom, next page data will be loaded.

**user click 40th item -> watch detail page (react-router) -> click back button**

The main page scroll top of the page and get 1st page data again.

**How to restore scroll position and datas** without Ajax call?

When I used Vue js, i’ve used 'keep-alive' element.
Help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React / redux how to maintain scroll positoin between routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135087/react-redux-how-to-maintain-scroll-positoin-between-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep-alive is really nice. Generally, if you want to preserve state, you look at using a Flux (Redux lib) design pattern to store your data in a global store. You can even add this to a single component use case and not use it anywhere else if you wish.

If you need to keep the component around you can look at hoisting the component up and adding a "display: none" style to the component there. This will preserve the Node and thus the component state along with it.

*Worth noting also is the "key" field helps the React engine figure out what tree should be unmounted and what should be kept. If you have the same component and want to preserve its state across multiple usages, maintain the key value. Conversely, if you want to ensure an unmount, just change the key value.*

Answer (score 5):

## If you are working with `react-router`

Component can not be cached while going forward or back which lead to **losing data and interaction** while using `Route`

Component would be unmounted when Route was unmatched

After reading source code of Route we found that using children prop as a function could help to control rendering behavior.

**Hiding instead of Removing** would fix this issue.

I am already fixed it with my tools [react-router-cache-route](https://github.com/CJY0208/react-router-cache-route)

### Usage

Replace `<Route>` with `<CacheRoute>`

Replace `<Switch>` with `<CacheSwitch>`

---

## If you want real `<KeepAlive />` for `React`

I have my implementation [react-activation](https://github.com/CJY0208/react-activation)

[Online Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-beaver-solkt)

### Usage

```
import KeepAlive, { AliveScope } from 'react-activation'

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  return (
    <AliveScope>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(show => !show)}>Toggle</button>
      {show && (
        <KeepAlive>
          <Test />
        </KeepAlive>
      )}
    </AliveScope>
  )
}
```

[image]
The implementation principle is easy to say.

Because `React` will unload components that are in the intrinsic component hierarchy, we need to extract the components in `<KeepAlive>`, that is, their `children` props, and render them into a component that will not be unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Until now the awnser is no unfortunately. But there's a issue about it in React repository: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12039

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the same, I found this library, which is said to be doing the same. Have not used though - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keep-alive