# Stop iframe from reloading

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, html-table

I am writing the **React** application and I have a table, where I render the iframe widget in each row. Whenever the position of the row is changing, the iframe of that row starts to reload. Is it possible to preserve the state of the iframe and stop it from reloading? Thank you!

React: v18

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823415/does-react-have-keep-alive-like-vue-js